# Simpletest is running all of my tests twice. Why?

Tags: php, tdd, simpletest

I have a simpletest suite I've been working on writing for some of my recent API wrapper code in PHP. But every time I run the test, it runs all of the tests twice.

My calling code:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/simpletest/autorun.php');  
require_once('CompanyNameAPI.php');


$test = new TestSuite('API test');
$test->addFile(dirname(__FILE__) . '/tests/authentication_test.php');
if (TextReporter::inCli()) {
    exit ($test->run(new TextReporter()) ? 0 : 1);
} else {
    $test->run(new HtmlReporter());
}
```

authentication_test.php looks like:

```
class Test_CallLoop_Authentication extends UnitTestCase {  

    function test_ClassCreate(){
        $class = new CallLoopAPI();
        $this->assertIsA($class, CallLoopAPI);
    }
        //More tests
}
```

There aren't any more includes to autorun.php or other calls to simpletest within authentication_test.php either.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your calling code like this:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/simpletest/autorun.php');  
require_once('CompanyNameAPI.php');

$test = new TestSuite('API test');
$test->addFile(dirname(__FILE__) . '/tests/authentication_test.php');
```

autorun.php file executes automatically your tests calling run() methods implicitly, when you call run() method you execute tests again.

Comment: I'm not a simpletest guru yet, but i've been reading documentation and it says that the code you try to use, is already embedded inside simpletest library so your test will automatically recognize wich reporter to use in case you use command line or browser. The code i suggested you in fact runs with appropriate Reporter in both browser and command line.

Answer (score 0):

From simpletests documentation, you should use the static method `prefer(REPORTER)`

```
<?php
require_once('show_passes.php');
require_once('simpletest/simpletest.php');
SimpleTest::prefer(new ShowPasses());
require_once('simpletest/autorun.php');

class AllTests extends TestSuite {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('All tests');
        $this->addFile(dirname(__FILE__).'/log_test.php');
        $this->addFile(dirname(__FILE__).'/clock_test.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I would tag this as the solution to my follow-up question, if I could tag more than one.